# How to check whether a string is a valid url

Tags: c#, .net

I use this code to valid url

```
public static bool isUrl(string text)
        {
            Uri uriResult;
            return Uri.TryCreate(text, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp;
        }
```

but this code, not working when i send parameters like google.com, www.google.com

it only work when i use http like http://google.com

i need a code for c#, like `Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(text).matches();` in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this regex.

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)
```

Here's the regex in action with this question's url: [image]

So if a match is found you got yourself a URL. And if in the future you need to get parts of it it can do that for you too.

Comment: Interesting in this regard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url